# How to combine Graphics primitives in a DynamicModule without breaking it

Tags: graphics, dynamic, gui-construction, broken-code

I am trying to present `Graphics` primitives dynamically. I want the displayed image to be able to update after the user changes the controls. An example would be something like

```
With[{triangle = {{0.13, 0.94}, {0.741, 0.744}, {0.77, 0.2}},
  DynamicModule[{ctrlx, ctrly, x, y, cond, epi, lab, gra},
   ctrlx=Row[{Framed[Control[{{x, 0.6, "x"}, 0, 1, 0.0001}], FrameStyle -> Thin], Spacer[10]}];
   ctrly=Row[{Framed[Control[{{y, 0.6, "y"}, 0, 1, 0.0001}], FrameStyle -> Thin], Spacer[10]}];

   cond=And[0.13<=x<0.9,0.2<=y<=0.567];

   lab = If[
    cond,
    Style[Row[#], Red, FontSize -> 14] & /@ {{"x=", x}, {"y=", y}},
    Style[Row[#], Black, FontSize -> 14] & /@ {{"x=", x}, {"y=", y}}
   ];

   gra = Graphics[
     {Opacity[0.1], FaceForm[Orange], EdgeForm[Purple], Polygon[rect]},

     Frame -> True,
     FrameLabel -> {
       {Null, Dynamic@lab[[1]]},
       {Null, Dynamic@lab[[2]]}
      },
     RotateLabel -> False,
     Epilog -> Dynamic@If[cond, 
       {Red, Point[{x, y}]}, 
       {Black, Point[{x, y}]}
      ],
     PlotRange -> {{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}},
     ImagePadding -> {{5, 70}, {5, 20}},
     ImageSize -> Medium
    ];

    Grid[{{gra}, {Column[{ctrlx, ctrly}]}}]

  ]
 ]
```

In this example, the controls change the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of a moving point.

Once the coordinates of that point enter a per-configured area (see `cond` at the code snippet above) the `FrameLabel`'s change color and so does the point itself (from `Black` to `Red`, see the following two images).

[image]

Now, the question is motivated by the results of the following changes in the code:

If I attempt to *bundle* together all the pieces of code that need to get *reevaluated* every time the controls change, namely when I modify the first `If` statement to read like this

```
{epi, {lblx, lbly}} = If[
  cond,
  {
    {Red, Point[{x, y}]},
    Style[Row[#], Red, FontSize -> 14] & /@ {{"x=", x}, {"y=", y}}
   },
  {
   {Black, Point[{x, y}]},
   Style[Row[#], Black, FontSize -> 14] & /@ {{"x=", x}, {"y=", y}}
  }
 ];
```

and after I perform the needed adjustments in the body of the `Graphics` ie after I adjust the following

```
FrameLabel -> {
  {Null, Dynamic@lblx},
  {Null, Dynamic@lbly}
 }
```

and

```
Epilog -> Dynamic@epi
```

the front end cannot evaluate it. It spits an error `Set::shape` with a text of

> Lists {epi\$1935,{lblx\$1935,lbly\$1935}} and
>   If[0.13<=x\$1935<0.9&&0.2<=y\$1935<=0.567,{{Red,Point[{x\$1935,y\$1935}]},(Style[Row[#1],Red,FontSize->14]&)/@{{x=,x\$1935},{y=,y\$1935}}},{{Black,Point[{x\$1935,y$1935}]},(Style[Row[#1],Black,FontSize->14]&)/@{{x=,x\$1935},{y=,y\$1935}}}]
>   are not the same shape.

Apparently, what the front ends informs the user is that the assignment in

```
{epi, {lblx, lbly}} = If[...]
```

does not work. I assume that happens because `cond` contains `x` and `y` which are in turn dynamically changing but I don't actually know why that is the case since in the former version of the code `cond` was similarly depended upon `x` and `y` and `If` evaluated just fine.

So the question is, how to make bundling together all the pieces of code that change when the controls change, work?

### PS

I include the code that reproduces the error message for convenience

```
With[{rect = {{0.13, 0.2}, {0.13, 0.567}, {0.9, 0.567}, {0.9, 0.2}}},
 DynamicModule[{ctrlx, ctrly, x, y, cond, epi, lblx, lbly, gra},
  ctrlx = Row[{Framed[Control[{{x, 0.6, "x"}, 0, 1, 0.0001}], FrameStyle -> Thin], Spacer[10]}];
  ctrly = Row[{Framed[Control[{{y, 0.6, "y"}, 0, 1, 0.0001}], FrameStyle -> Thin], Spacer[10]}];
  cond = And[0.13 <= x < 0.9, 0.2 <= y <= 0.567];
  {epi, {lblx, lbly}} = If[
    cond,
    {
     {Red, Point[{x, y}]},
     Style[Row[#], Red, FontSize -> 14] & /@ {{"x=", x}, {"y=", y}}
     },
    {
     {Black, Point[{x, y}]},
     Style[Row[#], Black, FontSize -> 14] & /@ {{"x=", x}, {"y=", y}}
    }
   ];
  gra = Graphics[
    {Opacity[0.1], FaceForm[Orange], EdgeForm[Purple], Polygon[rect]},
    Frame -> True,
    FrameLabel -> {
      {Null, Dynamic@lblx},
      {Null, Dynamic@lbly}
     },
    RotateLabel -> False,
    Epilog -> Dynamic@epi,
    PlotRange -> {{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}},
    ImagePadding -> {{20, 70}, {20, 20}},
    ImageSize -> Medium
   ];
  Grid[{{gra}, {Column[{ctrlx, ctrly}]}}],
  Deployed -> True
 ]
]
```

Comment: The more compact example the more likely you will get attention. Are you sure all this is essential to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have presented a stripped down version of my code; (I think) the problem is located in `{epi, {lblx, lbly}} =If[...]`; the rest of the code is minimally necessary in order for anyone to get a meaningfully reproducible example running; my main problem is that I need to display `Graphics` dynamically and that doesn't work when I group together all the things that need to change; I guess I could strip some more lines off but that would probably make the presentation more distant from what I think is useful; I am open to suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't want to expend the time it would take to itemize your errors, but I'm willing to show you a much simpler implementation that works. Comparing it with your own code should help you to determine what you did wrong.

```
With[{rect = {{0.13, 0.2}, {0.13, 0.567}, {0.9, 0.567}, {0.9, 0.2}}}, 
  DynamicModule[{x, y, color, lblx, lbly, gra},
    Dynamic @ 
      Column[
        {Dynamic @ gra,
         Row[
           {Invisible["****"],
            Framed[Control[{{x, 0.6, "x"}, 0, 1, 0.01}], FrameStyle -> Thin]}],
         Row[
           {Invisible["****"],
            Framed[Control[{{y, 0.6, "y"}, 0, 1, 0.01}], FrameStyle -> Thin]}]}],
    Initialization :> (
      color := If[And[0.13 <= x < 0.9, 0.2 <= y <= 0.567], Red, Black];
      lblx := Style[Row[{"x = ", x}], color, FontSize -> 14];
      lbly := Style[Row[{"y = ", y}], color, FontSize -> 14];
      gra =
       Graphics[
        {Opacity[0.1], FaceForm[Orange], EdgeForm[Purple], Polygon[rect]},
        Frame -> True,
        FrameLabel -> {{None, lblx}, {None, lbly}},
        RotateLabel -> False,
        Epilog -> {color, Point[{x, y}]},
        PlotRange -> {{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}},
        ImagePadding -> {{20, 70}, {20, 30}},
        ImageSize -> Medium])]]
```

[image: gui]

Basically your problems are improper application of `Dynamic` and improper initialization of variables.

#### Update

Because I think it's rather clumsy to move the point around with two sliders, I think you ought to consider using a locator pane in which you can simply drag the point around with the mouse.

```
With[{rect = {{0.13, 0.2}, {0.13, 0.567}, {0.9, 0.567}, {0.9, 0.2}}},
  DynamicModule[{pt = {.6, .6}, color, lblx, lbly},
    LocatorPane[
      Dynamic @ pt,
      Dynamic @ 
        Graphics[
          {{Opacity[0.1], FaceForm[Orange], EdgeForm[Purple], Polygon[rect]},
          {color, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[pt]}},
         Frame -> True,
         FrameLabel -> {{None, lblx}, {None, lbly}},
         RotateLabel -> False,
         PlotRange -> {{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}},
         ImagePadding -> {{20, 70}, {20, 30}},
         ImageSize -> Medium],
      {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, .01 {1, 1}},
      Appearance -> None],
    Initialization :> (
      color := If[And[0.13 <= pt[[1]] < 0.9, 0.2 <= pt[[2]] <= 0.567], Red, Black];
      lblx := Style[Row[{"x = ", pt[[1]]}], color, FontSize -> 14];
      lbly := Style[Row[{"y = ", pt[[2]]}], color, FontSize -> 14])]]
```

[image: locator]

Comment: within the `Initialization` block eg `color` receives a delayed assignment associating it with dynamic variables `x` and `y`; should I interpret the fact that the assignment *does not* contain any pattern (eg there is no  `color[x_,y_]:=<x,y>` ) as an indication that, in fact, `color` depends on *global* (within the module) variables `x` and `y`? Can I treat code within the `Initialization` block as having access to '*globals*' defined in the `DynamicModule`? Thank you.

Comment: @user42582. Since the variables used in the initialization are all specified in the 1st argument of `DynamicModule`, the are all ***local*** to the module  (defined over and only over the scope of the module). That makes them available anywhere in the module when it runs. The `SetDelayed` expressions defined in the initialization are dynamically evaluated whenever the value of `pt` changes; therefore, they use the current value of `pt`. To get that behavior is whole reason for writing the initialization code in the way it appears.